# AngularJs scope - how to get scope from DOM correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a custom directive with its own isolated scope:

```
angular.module('app').directive('custom', function(){
    return {
      scope: {
        text: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element){
        alert(scope.$id);
        alert(element.scope().$id);
      }
    }
  })
```

It is bound to a single h1 tag: `<h1 custom text="Hello Plunker!"></h1>`

Could someone explain me why I am getting different scope values on first and second alert?
It there a way to get my isolated scope using DOM element and scope() call?

Thanks in advance

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mdLS5eZAqw4YBWwLZWbo

Comment: From what it seems `element.scope()` gets the main scope. `scope` is the child scope of `element.scope()`. Why it is, i'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope` refers to the scope of the directive, an isolated scope.

`element.scope()`refers to the scope associated with that element.

To get the isolated scope through `element`you can call `element.isolateScope()`.